# Follow up: MySQL service not working. Cannot access PHPMyAdmin after setting new password

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I recently asked a question on [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868846/mysql-and-phpmyadmin-issue-locked-out-cant-get-back-in)

I had some help, but my question was not resolved. I still do not have access to phpmyadmin and mysql is not functioning properly. Here is where I am at right now.

I ran this code:

```
$ systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-01-10 09:17:03 CST; 16s ago
Process: 15561 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 15556 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 15561 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 15562 (mysql-systemd-s)
CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
 └─control
 |─15562 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
 └─15623 sleep 1

Jan 10 09:17:03 logan-Latitude-E6320 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Jan 10 09:17:06 logan-Latitude-E6320 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

I previously tried to uninstall and reinstall everything. Here is that process:

```
logan@logan-Latitude-E6320:~$ sudo rm -f /var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag
logan@logan-Latitude-E6320:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
   mysql-server-5.7
Suggested packages:
   mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-5.7
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 195 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,597 kB of archives.
After this operation, 48.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 230105 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up libevent-core-2.0-5:amd64 (2.0.21-stable-2) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/init.d/mysql ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/logrotate.d/mysql-server ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/mysql/debian-start ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: warning: not replacing /etc/mysql/my.cnf with a link
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
  mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
   Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                      Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
 Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
  mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I believe that this issue is with /usr/bin/dpkg (since it is what is returning the error code, however I do not know how to resolve the issue. Does anyone know what steps to take to reach a resolution?

Any advice is welcome, I appreciate your help in advance.

If you need any further information, please let me know.

Edit 1: This question has been identified as a possible duplicate of another question. That possible duplicate is the previous question that I asked, which did not produce a solution to the problem.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I appreciate that help, but that was my previous post which did not reach a resolution.

Comment: Lets start with the basics. "dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server" This is not really a surprise as previous output indicates that you have"195 not upgraded" packages. It's likely due to this that you can't configure mysql-server to complete installation. Begin with the command `sudo apt-get update&&sudo apt-get upgrade` to bring your packages up to date. Since everything else depends on this succeeding you have to start here. The output is there to give you clues about what is happening. Watch it closely. Don't try to resolve the last issue before resolving the 1st.

Comment: @LoganMusselman you shouldn't repost questions, even if it's been a while. What you can do is delete the old one and create a new one _if the new one has new info_, but I don't recommend you do that, and suggest you edit your existing question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about what you did, if you changed the mysql password you need to change the password phpadmin has stored to acces PHP in the file "config.inc.php".

You can read something here. [How to change root password for mysql and phpmyadmin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118772/how-to-change-root-password-for-mysql-and-phpmyadmin)

Comment: I opened the config.inc.php file and I cannot find the line: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'yourpassword';

Comment: Try to find similar line, if not google where the phpadmin stores the password maybe I read a wrong entry. The point is that if you changed mysql password without changing phpadmin now it cant access beacause the config is not right.